# $_REQUEST does not have index

Tags: php, optimization

I'm using querystring with `$_REQUEST` array and each time I want to access an any key I use this condition

```
if(array_key_exists('scene_id', $_REQUEST))
```

Is there any way to directly use `$_REQUEST["scene_id"]` without any warnings and errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap that in your own function ofcourse:

```
function request($key, $default=null) {
    return isset($_REQUEST[$key])
        ? $_REQUEST[$key]
        : $default;
}

echo request('scene_id');
```

Comment: I don't know where you got that idea, but it's crazy. functions exist to make code more readable. They do this by making it contain less repeated boilerplate. ask 1000000 programmers and they will tell you the same.

Comment: I only ask my boss about these concepts :) since he is the moneyholder :/

Comment: I think and decide, you have the answer flag. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['scene_id']))
```

or

```
$scene_id = isset($_REQUEST['scene_id']) ? $_REQUEST['scene_id'] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Most prefred metthod would be to use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  `if(isset($_REQUEST['scene_id']))` but you can actually suppress the error messages using `@` sign but please note that the error would still exist and would would need to handle it correctly

From PHP Documentation

`PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.`

Example 1

```
if(@$_REQUEST['scene_id'])
{
    echo "ok" ;
}
```

Example 2 (  Filter , Validation or  Exception )

```
try {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['scene_id']))
        throw new Exception("Missing Scene ID");

    if (!filter_var($_REQUEST['scene_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT))
        throw new Exception("Only Valid Number Allowed");

    echo "Output ", $_REQUEST['scene_id'];
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea.   why suppress an error in code when you can use another option to fix it.  Bad Idea.  Use `isset`

Comment: @betterer i think you should read the question again `directly use $_REQUEST["scene_id"] without any warning(s) and error(s)` suppression does not mean you can not do proper filter & validation . He does want to any function but access `$_REQUEST["scene_id"]` directly

Comment: @Baba  You can `directly use $_REQUEST["scene_id"] without any warning(s) and error(s)` by using `isset($_REQUEST['scene_id'])`

Comment: @bretterer  he is already aware of that using `isset` .. just looking for alternative

Comment: @bretterer, why you suppress us :) I do not want to use `isset`s everywhere.

Comment: @Enes Unal Some people just downvote & make comment without having to understand what the person asking the question wants all for quick points

Comment: @Baba, I agree with you. wish we can do something about it, but we can just do not mind them..

Comment: iirc, this will be completely impossible in some next version of php. looking for docs now

Comment: @Kris .. It would be Interesting to know the version of PHP

Comment: I'm using php with the version 5.3.8

Comment: @Enes Unal Works perfectly on version 5.3.8

Comment: @Baba: i think it must've been someones wishlist for php 5.5 that my memory is confusing with actual docs. Couldn't find anything official from php (zend) on this in the past 15 or so minutes. likelyhood my memory is flawed seems high.

Comment: @Kris .. have checked myself .. but i don't think i deserved to be down voted without no valid justification

Comment: @Baba, I half agree with you. But I also believe we have a responsibility as a community to not teach bad code practices, no matter how good it might fit with the question. On the other hand, I didn't downvote this

Comment: @kris .. thanks for not down voting me .. using `@is not a bad`  .. it `how you use @ can be bad` ..  can actually be very useful in some instances  .. It just like saying `eval` is bad ...

Comment: @Baba: Almost nothing is inherently bad, I do downvote bad advice when I see it. On a more personal note, I would like php better if there was no way of supressing errors other then dealing with them. I'd also like a `finally` clause and better namespacing/module packaging, and... too bad this is the real world.

Comment: @kris .. I love the introduction of `finally` i think i finally get you now .. `The errors is not actually suppressed` its the `any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.` - PHP DOC .... Thanks anyway I would updated my answer for other people

Comment: @Baba:  much better answer here than just saying to suppress the error.  it teaches good code practice as an option.  I removed the down vote from me

Answer (score 0):

You can prepopulate $_REQUEST with default values before you test for them:

```
$expected = array(
    'scene_id'=>false,
    'another_var'=>'foo',
);

foreach($exptected as $key=>$default) {

    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$key])) {
        $_REQUEST[$key] = $default;
    }

}

if ($_REQUEST['scene_id') {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: too much work to do. Decreases code follow and readablity to others.